# Web-Services (Loading JSON data wth JQUERY using a Button)

Tags: json, web-development-server

I need help on the following: I cannot get the JQuery to load the JSON data even though the JSON file is firing in the console.

Here is the HTML code;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script><!-- places Javascript reference file in html-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stylesheet.css"> <!--places css in sub folder-->

    <title>H</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="vanilla_ajax">
</div>
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="loadAJAX()">Change to AJAX</button>
<div id="jq_ajax">
</div>
<button type="button" id="button2" onclick="loadJQUERY()">Change to JQUERY</button>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The first button loads and is fine so I have excluded that portion. It is the second one "loadJQuery()" that does not render on the screen. Here is the Javascript for it:

```
function loadJQUERY(){
  /*place holder for ajax loading using JQuery*/
  $('#jq_ajax').append('<p id = "test">'); //jq test
  $.ajax({
    url: "data/Holder.json",
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
      $("#jq_ajax").html("<p>" + result.data + "</p>");
    }
  });
}
```

The pathway for the folder is correct as it works with the XML/Ajax version.

Answer (score 0):

the JSON file was using single quotes instead of double quotes. That was the issue